# How to setup my character class structure

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

---

I need to be able to identify if the Character isPlayer and use that to determine the output of toString().

What is the best way to handle my class setup and structure, or do I need to look into an alternative and what that might look like?

General thoughts on alternative ways to handle this:

- Define methods for each class in Character class (raceToString, hairToString)

Code:

```cs
public abstract class Base
{
   public abstract string toString();
}

public enum Tag
{
   Human,
   Elf,
   Blonde,
   Black
}

public class Character
{
   public bool isPlayer;
   public string Name;
   
   public Race race;
   public Hair hair;
}

public class Race : Base
{
   public Tag tag;

   public override string toString()
   {
      if (isPlayer)
      {
         return $"You are a {tag}.";
      }

   }
}

public class Hair : Base
{
   public Tag tag;

   public override string toString()
   {
      return $"You have {tag} hair.";
   }
}

void TestFunction()
{
    Character character = new Character();
    character.isPlayer = true;
    character.race.tag = Tag.Human;
    character.hair.tag = Tag.Blonde;
    
    Console.WriteLine(character.race.toString());
    Console.WriteLine(character.hair.toString());
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `toString()` when there's already a `ToString()` that you can override, and is used throughout the system?  What is a `Tag`?  As a type it seems very confused about what it represents.  In this model a character's "race" can be "Blonde" and their "hair" can be "Human"?  Why?  And why does every attribute of a character need to be wrapped in a class instead of just holding a value for that attribute?  Overall it sounds like (1) this structure is very, very strange and (2) the question itself is very subjective and likely not a good fit for this community.

Comment: ^^ PLUS: Even if all this was safe and sound: It is none of the `Hair` class's business how it is output. i.e. it shouldn't _have_ a "toString" (that is used to form strings that are shown in any form of UI). At most such a function may return a string _representation of its value_. Otherwise you'll soon find yourself in trouble because your app prints "You are a Human cannot perform You are a Elf specific actions" or similar nonsense.